# Is it possible to group a stringified table that has a column with multiline using regex?

Tags: regex

My goal is to parse this string into a table. My first thought of solution is regular expression. However, I found it to be challenging.

The string:

```
      01/07          SALDO AWAL                                                                                                                       6,000.49
      01/07          TRSF E-BANKING DB                0107/WESAD/WA23031                                           1,500.00 DB                        4,500.49
                                                      Q0344XXXXX12
                                                      SASA SASX SASX
      01/07          TRSF E-BANKING DB                0107/QEZDF/WSA2321                                         1,500.00 DB
                                                      12308/DASX
                                                      -
                                                      -
                                                      113456758
      01/07          TRANSAKSI DEBIT                  TGL: 01/07                                                 1,500.00 DB                           1,500.49
                                                      QR 014
                                                      00000.00SSP&SASZ
      04/07          TRSF E-BANKING DB                0207/QEZDF/WSA2321                                           500.00 DB
                     TANGGAL :02/07                   Q0344XXXXX12
                                                      SALZXA YAEAS SAX
      04/07          TRSF E-BANKING DB                0207/FTFVA/WS95031                                         500.00 DB
                     TANGGAL :02/07                   12208/SAXZX
                                                      -
                                                      -
                                                      113456758
      04/07          TRSF E-BANKING CR                0307/FTSCY/WS95271                                      2,000.00                            2,500.49
                     TANGGAL :03/07                            2000.00
                                                      dsa dsds
                                                      SAX SAX DAZ
```

What I've tried:

1. Regex `\d{2}/\d{2}[^\n]*`.

   The problem is that it captures `TANGGAL :02/07                   Q0344XXXXX12`.
2. Regex `(\d{2}\/\d{2}) +([\w-]+(?: [\w-]+)*) +([\w/:.,]+(?: [\w/:.,]+)*) +([\w,.]+(?: [\w,.]+)*) *([\d,.]*)`

   The problem is that, it did not capture the column 3 **completely**

```
      01/07          TRSF E-BANKING DB                0107/WESAD/WA23031                                           1,500.00 DB                        4,500.49
                                                      Q0344XXXXX12
                                                      SASA SASX SASX
```

It will only capture

```
      01/07          TRSF E-BANKING DB                0107/WESAD/WA23031                                           1,500.00 DB                        4,500.49
```

and it ignore

```
                                                      Q0344XXXXX12
                                                      SASA SASX SASX
```

Comment: @anubhava My goal is to capture the `Q0344XXXXX12 SASA SASX SASX` into group 3. The regex you propose does not capture it. And after double check, I found out that both your second regex and mine have a bug, it captures `SALDO` as group 2 and `AWAL` as group 3.

Comment: Are the columns separated by tabs `\t`?

Comment: regex matching is from left to right, not vertical. You need a different tool to process the data

Comment: @anubhava so it is not possible with regex. Do you have any suggestion for the tool?

Comment: awk can be a good tool if you're on unix/linux

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have asked the same question multiple times here. I have created a regex solution, that separates the columns into groups, only based on the fact that they are separated by spaces (different number of spaces in each group).

The regex matches everything, but creates groups for each column. Non existing columns creates groups, that are `undefined`. The regex uses this pattern for each column:

```
(-|\b(?:[^ ]|[ ][^ ])+\b)?(?:[ ]{2,15}|\r?$)
```

**Explanation**:

`(` - create a group

`-|\b` - match a hyphen or word boundary

`(?:` - create a non capturing group

`[^ ]` - match a non space

`|` - OR

`[ ][^ ]` - a space and a non space

`)+` - match this one or more times

`\b` - match a word boundary

`)?` - end the group and make it optional

`(?:` - create a non capturing group

`[ ]{2,15}` - match 2 to 15 spaces

`|` - OR

`\r?$` - end of line

`)` - end the group

All groups follow this pattern except for the number of spaces. Well, the last group has no spaces after it.

**Here's the complete regex:**

```
^[ ]{6}(-|\b(?:[^ ]|[ ][^ ])+\b)?(?:[ ]{2,15}|\r?$)(-|\b(?:[^ ]|[ ][^ ])+\b)?(?:[ ]{2,33}|\r?$)(-|\b(?:[^ ]|[ ][^ ])+\b)?(?:[ ]{2,56}|\r?$)(-|\b(?:[^ ]|[ ][^ ])+\b)?(?:[ ]{2,36}|\r?$)(-|\b(?:[^ ]|[ ][^ ])+\b)?\r?$
```

The regex requires the `**multiline**` option.

I read from on of your other questions that you want to create a CSV file. You can do that by replacing the matches with this pattern:

```
"$1","$2","$3","$4","$5"
```

**Now you should get this CSV:**

```
"01/07","SALDO AWAL","","","6,000.49"
"01/07","TRSF E-BANKING DB","0107/WESAD/WA23031","1,500.00 DB","4,500.49"
"","","Q0344XXXXX12","",""
"","","SASA SASX SASX","",""
"01/07","TRSF E-BANKING DB","0107/QEZDF/WSA2321","1,500.00 DB",""
"","","12308/DASX","",""
"","","-","",""
"","","-","",""
"","","113456758","",""
"01/07","TRANSAKSI DEBIT","TGL: 01/07","1,500.00 DB","1,500.49"
"","","QR 014","",""
"","","00000.00SSP&SASZ","",""
"04/07","TRSF E-BANKING DB","0207/QEZDF/WSA2321","500.00 DB",""
"","TANGGAL :02/07","Q0344XXXXX12","",""
"","","SALZXA YAEAS SAX","",""
"04/07","TRSF E-BANKING DB","0207/FTFVA/WS95031","500.00 DB",""
"","TANGGAL :02/07","12208/SAXZX","",""
"","","-","",""
"","","-","",""
"","","113456758","",""
"04/07","TRSF E-BANKING CR","0307/FTSCY/WS95271","2,000.00","2,500.49"
"","TANGGAL :03/07","2000.00","",""
"","","dsa dsds","",""
"","","SAX SAX DAZ","",""
```

Having the data in a standard format should give you more options to manipulate it further, if needed.

I have created a test case for you [here](https://bak-o-soft.dk/RegExp/JSRegExpBuilder/D5IJ7Q) (it uses javascript but the regex should work in all decent flavors). Press '**MatchAll**' to see the matches. Seeing the matches is not really interesting, since it matches all, so press the '**Detailed table**' to see the groups and press '**ReplaceAll**' to see the CSV.